# Awk hack to crack based on count

Tags: unix, awk, split

I have the below file which starts with `;%%%%` which is to be split

````
```;%%%ab3579trffe4630
    b3579trffe463
    fhterringsbfkfgott
  ${79trsroiuffe4630
  fhterringsbfkfgott
   ${ab3579trffe4630
  fhterringsbfkfgott
  ${trffe4630bgtrep
fhterringsbfkfgott```
````

File 1:

```````
``````;%%%ab3579trffe4630
    b3579trffe463
    fhterringsbfkfgott
  ${79trsroiuffe4630
  fhterringsbfkfgott```
```````

file 2:

````
``` ;%%%ab3579trffe4630
  fhterringsbfkfgott
  ${trffe4630bgtrep
fhterringsbfkfgott```
````

Now I am able to get the delimiter count and saving it in a variable
to split the file I want use the variable and pattern to split so that there is no data loss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -v mark='${' -v c=2 'index($0,mark) {++i} 
                                          {print > ("file."int((i-1)/c+1))}' file
```

or simpler

```
 $ awk -v mark='${' -v c=2 'index($0,mark){f="file." int(i++/c+1)} {print > f}'

$ head file.?
==> file.1 <==
${ab3579trffe4630
    b3579trffe463
    fhterringsbfkfgott
  ${79trsroiuffe4630
  fhterringsbfkfgott

==> file.2 <==
   ${ab3579trffe4630
  fhterringsbfkfgott
  ${trffe4630bgtrep
fhterringsbfkfgott
```

assumes marks only appear one per line.  You specify the count per split file.

increment a counter when the literal mark in encountered in a line.  Print the line to a file, the file name suffix is arranges so that up to `c` will go to the first file, next batch to second, etc.

Since you're using special chars, this is not a regex match, therefore you can't specify `|` condition.

For literal match to multiple marks, you can do

```
$ awk -v marks='${|$^' -v c=2 '
        BEGIN{n=split(marks,m,"|"); f="file.1"} 
             {for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
                if(index($0,m[i])) 
                   {f="file." int(fc++/c+1); break}} 
             {print > f}' file
```

perhaps it might be easier to escape the regex chars and just do a regex match instead.

Comment: did you copy/paste?  There should't be a open brace before `BEGIN`

Comment: yep copied as it is, didnt see a open brace though It still gives the error near {  {print > f}' file}

Comment: where are those extra braces coming from `{ {print > f}' file}`?  Also please check your `awk` version.